# How to ensure orderly processing result of a websocket's callbacks?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, asynchronous, websocket

*I have an application which listens to a websocket endpoint and processes the data received from it and saves it to a database*.

**The problem** of race condition arises when two callbacks are invoked concurrently (for example: one task may begin processing, then another task may begin processing and update the database, then the first task may update the database - so in the end the database updates are out of order).

**The solution** I thought of was to *record the exact time a callback is called,* process the data, then attach the time to the data passed to the database and in the database compare this time with the last update time and act accordingly.
**One possible problem** I thought of is that the time may be recorded out of order (for example: consider the scenario where the first callback is called, then the second callback is called and the time is recorded, then the time is recorded for the first callback).

How would you do it the right way? Solutions to this problem or other ways to go about it?

**EDIT**: *To be more specific as I'm intending for the program to be as real-time as possible I'd like to allow for the most up-to-date callback to be processed without delay (without waiting for all other previous callbacks to entirely process) but to ensure that the end result of the processing (as is recorded in the database) adheres to the order in which the callbacks arrived (is not corrupt)*

Comment: You can use promises to create a mutex / lock that forces each callback to wait for the previous one  to finish.

Comment: @SLaks I wouldn't want to lock around the entire processing segments as they could be rather lengthy and would slow the program which should be real-time. unless I misunderstood your suggestion - what do you mean by use _promises_ to create lock?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can the data handler callback return a promise of when it's finished.

Each time you get a new data from the socket, wait for that promise before handling it, then store the resulting promise for the next data to wait for.

That would look like this:

```
const ready = Promise.resolve();

socket.on(..., data => {
  ready = ready.then(() => processData(data);
});
```

This will have no effect on any other code.

**EDIT**: To do expensive work outside the lock, you can write

```
socket.on(..., data => {
  const result = doExpensiveWork(data); // Returns a promise
  ready = Promise.all(result, ready).then(([result]) => insertData(result));
});
```

Comment: That's an interesting suggestion which answers the question and I guess can be implemented using .NET's SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync(). However my intentions where more specific and I apologize for not making them clear enough - as I'm intending for the program to be as real-time as possible I'd like to allow for the most up-to-date callback to be processed without delay (without waiting for all other previous callbacks to entirely process) but to ensure that the end result of the processing (as is recorded in the database) adheres to the order in which the callbacks arrived (is not corrupt).

Comment: I will update the question, and if there's no fitting answer for the edited question, I'll accept yours as it was valid before the editing.

Comment: @AKL: Then you can start gather data immediately, and only wait for the promise lock when it's time to insert into the database.

Comment: That's a nice approach! But I think it introduces a similar problem to the solution I suggested in the question? what if two callbacks fire straight one after the other (in two separate tasks) and there's a context switch such that the first task executes the second line (doExpensiveWork()) [context switch] the second task executes the second and third lines (doExpensiveWork() and Promise.All()) [context switch] the first task executes the third line (Promise.All())?

Comment: yeh but if the scenario I've given in the previous comment happens then ready will be assigned the second task's future before it's assigned the first task's future, wouldn't it?

Comment: No; `ready` is assigned synchronously, without waiting for anything.

Comment: oh I see what you mean, so I guess socket.on() is always invoked on the same thread (I'm not a js dev).. I should check if that's the situation in my case also.